# Install Visual Studio Community 2017 through Powershell or Ansible

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, ansible, visual-studio-2017

I need to install vs2017 community through powershell or ansible. i have the .exe file but I'm not able to pass it parameters for continue the installation. I have tried this, based on another question:

vs_community.exe --lang en-US --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Node --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreTools --includeRecommended

but installation doesn't seem to start. Does anyone know what could I do? or about some useful documentation?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

check here

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_package_module.html

- name: Install Visual C thingy with list of arguments instead of a string, and permanent log
  win_package:
  path: http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/B/16B06F60-3B20-4FF2-B699-5E9B7962F9AE/VSU_4/vcredist_x64.exe
  product_id: '{CF2BEA3C-26EA-32F8-AA9B-331F7E34BA97}'
  arguments:

  - /install
  - /passive
  - /norestart

may be worth a try